# Find last occurrence of character in string without built-in function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to make a function in Python 2.7 that does not use any built-in functions to find the last occurrence of a character in a string. It should work like:

```
string="This is a string with plenty of eeeeees"
string.rfind("e")
```

But the `.rfind` has to be replaced with a function created in the code like:

```
def lastocc(string, char):
    # Function code
```

Comment: What you need to do is replace `# Function code` with some code that does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will iterate over your string, and if it finds the matching character updates the `found_at` variable with the index of it in the string. It also uses the common idiom of returning `-1` if the character is not present in the string.

```
def last_occurence(s, char):
    found_at = -1
    index = 0
    for s_char in s:
        if s_char == char:
            found_at = index
        index += 1

    return found_at
```

If you could use the `len()` built-in, you could start your iteration from the end of the string, and take the length-negative_index to find it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that there is not too much built-in functions:

```
    def lastocc(string, char):
       m=-1;
       i=0;
       while i>=0:
          try:
             if string[i]==char:
                m=i;
             i+=1
          except Exception:
             i=-1;
       return(m);

   print(lastocc("1234561234", "0"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def lastocc(somestr, char):
    return max(i for i,c in enumerate(somestr) if c==char)
```

Or if you don't want to use any builtins whatsoever, you could do this:

```
def lastocc(somestr, char):
    if not somestr: return -1
    if somestr[-1] == char: return len(somestr)-1
    return lastocc(somestr[:-1], char)
```

Comment: What about `len`, that's a built-in!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: touche. But I think it still fits the parameters of OP's homework

Comment: Possibly, but who knows?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I think I should teach a python course at a university - it would be so easy to find plagiarizers

Comment: With some built-ins, you could also make the first case avoid processing more than needed. `return len(somestr) - next((i for i, c in enumerate(reversed(somestr)) if c == char), len(somestr)) - 1`. Note: Didn't say this was a good way, it's just a way to get an early out and avoid processing the whole string when the "needle" exists.